# How to do this with foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a table called `categories`, with the following fields:

- id (primary key, identifies the categories)
- user_id (foreign key, `users.id`, the creator of the current category)
- category_id (foreign key, `categories.id`, the id of the parent category id)

Inside this table I have some records that are accessible to everyone.

For these records, both the `user_id` and the `category_id` fields are `NULL`.

In addition, users can create their own records *(where the `user_id` field is not `NULL`)*, but every user can access only those that he has made himself.

Each record must meet these conditions:

- `user_id` values must be valid
- if the `category_id` is given then it must be a valid `categories.id` and that record must be created by the given user
- the value of the `category_id` can be a `categoies.id` where the `user_id` is `NULL`

**How can I do this? I think I need more foreign keys for this, but not sure how to do it.**

Some examples that may help you to understand my problem:

Lets say I have the following records inside the `categories` table:

```
+--------+-------------+-----------------+
|   id   |   user_id   |   category_id   |
+--------+-------------+-----------------+
|   1    |     NULL    |      NULL       |
+--------+-------------+-----------------+
|   2    |     NULL    |      NULL       |
+--------+-------------+-----------------+
|   3    |      1      |        1        |
+--------+-------------+-----------------+
|   4    |      2      |        1        |
+--------+-------------+-----------------+
```

and lets say that I want to insert these records:

```
+-------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|   user_id   |   category_id   | is it insertable?                        
+-------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|   1         |     NULL        | yes, because the value of the user_id is valid id              |
+-------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|   1         |     1           | yes, because the record with id of 1 is created by NULL        |
+-------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|   1         |     3           | yes, because the record with id of 3 is created by user #1     |
+-------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|   1         |     4           | no, because the record with id of 4 is created by another user |
+-------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Categories table:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('income','expense') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'income',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `categories`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `category_id` (`category_id`,`user_id`,`name`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`);

ALTER TABLE `categories`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `categories_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `categories_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL foreign keys can go so far. This is a bit of advanced logic. Might I recommend using a MySQL trigger?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `check_categories_user_id`(IN p_category_id INT(11), IN p_user_id INT(11))
BEGIN
    IF (p_category_id IS NOT NULL) THEN

        SET @other_user_id = (SELECT user_id
           FROM categories
           WHERE id = p_category_id);              

        IF (p_user_id <> @other_user_id) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'check constraint on categories.user_id failed';
        END IF;
   END IF;
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER `categories_before_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `categories`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL check_categories_user_id(new.category_id, new.user_id);
END$$


CREATE TRIGGER `categories_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `categories`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL check_categories_user_id(new.category_id, new.user_id);
END$$   
DELIMITER ;
```

See dbfiddle [<kbd>here</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/X9wEuZ56grrSR7D9PtEHz/0). (If you remove the last INSERT query, the SELECT query works as expected)

Additionally, to avoid some overhead (The SELECT query in the trigger), you can just enforce NULL on user_id when category_id IS NOT NULL (Using triggers like above). If category_id is NOT NULL, you'll just fetch the user_id from the parent row (Or the root row (parent's parent row...etc), if nested).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What do you think? I've been playing with fiddle, and I don't think there is another way to approach this situation. Nested tables can be a bit tricky in MySQL, and I don't see any other way to do this without using some sort of a trigger.

Comment: I can't argue against this, but I agree that just keys/unique constraints alone probably can't work (hence my deleted answer).